# Start visual studio with different settings

Tags: visual-studio-2012, settings

I work off a laptop and switch between 4 screens (3x23" and the laptop screen at work) and just the laptop screen at home when using visual studio 2012.

I'd like to have a way at work I can arrange my windows (solution explorer, output, etc) to appear on other monitors so I have maximum room for my code but I woudl also like to be able to fire VS up when at home and not have to rearrange the windows each time back to suitable positions (and then back again when I get to work).

Do window positions get saved with visual studio settings files and is there a way to launch visual studio 2012 with a certain settings file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two different .vssettings files, one for work, and one for home, and then create shortcuts to launch VS with the different settings file depending on your location.

e.g. at home: `devenv.exe /ResetSettings “<path to settings>\home.vssettings”`

and at work: `devenv.exe /ResetSettings “<path to settings>\work.vssettings”`

Have a look at this article, it's for VS 2010 but I would bet that VS 2012 behaves similarly regarding settings: http://blog.zwezdin.com/en/49. I have used this approach and it works nicely.